Best memory / storage solution for high read / write throughput application(s)?
I have an application that uses a Raspberry Pi Model 4B (4GB RAM) running Raspberry Pi OS. Initially I was flashing the OS image to an SD card (and using that for storage as well), but I wanted faster read / write performance, so I switched to booting from a USB flash drive (and using that for storage as well). My application runs for long periods of time, sometimes days at a time, and involves writing to multiple CSV files multiple times per second. After a few months of running this application, however, it looks like the USB flash drive is starting to fail. I have gotten a similar error on bootup on a few separate occasions over the last few weeks:
(initramfs) usb 2-1: device not accepting address 4, error -71
(initramfs) usb 2-1: device not accepting address 5, error -71
(initramfs) usb 2-1: device not accepting address 6, error -71
(initramfs) usb usb2-port1: unable to enumerate USB device


What is a good solution here? Obviously, I need to replace this flash drive, but if I replace it with another identical one then I will likely just have this same problem in another month or two. I would prefer whatever form of storage I choose to last years rather than weeks or months. It looks like USB flash drives, SD cards, and even the onboard eMMC storage (for the Pi CM4 boards) are all in the same boat of not supporting numerous read / write operations (especially non-sequential).
Could I just get an SSD with a USB adapter and connect that directly to my Pi? Is it possible to boot from an SSD (not SD card or USB flash drive)? Or would I need to boot from an SD card and just put the filesystem on an SSD?
Also is it possible to make any adjustments to my current system to improve or extend the lifetime of the USB flash drives? Like changing OS log verbosity or write cycle delay or something?
I really appreciate any help or insight!

look at this: https://thepihut.com/products/ssd-to-usb-3-0-cable-for-raspberry-pi

USB sticks mostly use low quality flash memory and how much wear leveling they use is unknown. Better use an real SSD. The best way would be switching to a RasPi 5 + M.2 Hat module + a common M2 PciExpress SSD.

Are you using the whole 4GB of RAM? Can you just have your program saving to a tmpfs ram disk such as /tmp and then synchronise what you need to on a daily basis?

Agree with @Mokubai. When your application crashes or the pi loses power, you'll create a gap in your data anyway, so it probably won't matter if you lose another few minutes. If you can change your app to collect the csv data in RAM, and flush it out to the CSV files every 5 or 10 minutes, you'll reduce writes to the storage and wear drastically without having to add an SSD interface + SSD.

Homeassistant also writes a bunch of data every minute, depending on the sensors involved and I have been running mine on either a SSD via USB or NVMe via USB for years without issue.  I have over 100 sensors worth of continuous data.  Now I did buy better quality SSD like the samsung evo so I can't speak for every SSD as there are super cheap less reliable SSD out there.


What is a good solution here?

Well, the most reliable and robust solution would be to get a Pi5, buy an M.2 HAT module for it, and get an NVMe drive.
Your next best option is going to be a USB 3 to NVMe adapter, or USB 3 to SATA adapter, and a proper storage device to go with them.
The unfortunate reality is that USB is not great for storage to begin with, and flash drives tend to compound this issue since they usually have cheap flash storage and don’t do a good job of optimizing for it’s lifetime (yes, even the fancy expensive ones).

Is it possible to boot from an SSD (not SD card or USB flash drive)

If you can boot from a USB flash drive, you can boot from any other USB mass storage device as well.¹
However, I would argue in favor of putting the root filesystem and the the firmware partition on the SD card, and only putting the filesystem for the application data on the USB device. With sufficient setup, that both ensures your system will still be bootable if the USB device catastrophically fails, and that you can potentially recover from minor issues with the USB connection.

Also is it possible to make any adjustments to my current system to improve or extend the lifetime of the USB flash drives? Like changing OS log verbosity or write cycle delay or something?

Top of the list would be configuring journald to log to memory only, and then installing a regular syslog daemon to handle persistent logs. This would mean you lose out on journald features for persistent logs, but journald is likely the single biggest contributor to block rewrites on the filesystem after your application.

1: Probably at least. The USB Mass Storage Class is actually really complicated in unexpected ways, and there are subtypes of USB MSC device that are not well supported to begin with, on top of the Pi firmware probably not supporting most subtypes. Subtypes 1 (most cheap flash drives) and 6 (USB Attached SCSI, plus a few other types of device) should both work and they account for a vast majority of devices you’ll ever see, but it’s very unlikely that you could, for example, boot using subtype 3 (used for USB tape drives, which are a thing that actually exists despite how crazy that sounds).


Could I just get an SSD with a USB adapter and connect that directly
to my Pi?

Yes, you can. Or any pre-made USB external SSD drive or even old HDDs (slower).

Is it possible to boot from an SSD (not SD card or USB flash drive)?

If you can boot from a USB flash drive you can boot from any other USB mass storage device.

Or would I need to boot from an SD card and just put the filesystem on
an SSD?

You don't need to but you can if you want. Needless to say such setup requires solid knowledge of the boot process, partitions and bootloader(s) installation requirements. On the other hand, you can apply the same process you already tested successfully with the USB stick.

I am currently booting a Raspberry Pi 4 using a 120 GB SSD in a USB-3 external enclosure. I only had to flash the 32 GB SD card image to the SSD. I may decide to expand the partition later but it is working fine as it is now.

As @Robert noted, the underlying issue may be the lack of proper wear leveling on cheap USB drives. It's likely that your large number of writes wore out very few blocks on the device (in particular the ones that hold the directory entries for the locations of your CSV files) while the rest of the device was perfectly fine.
If that's the case, then your choice of hardware is fine, but you should make changes on the software side:

put your CSV files on a dedicated partition on that USB drive
format that partition with a log-structured file system (and not with the default ext4) so that file system takes care of the wear leveling. Some log-structured file systems available on Linux are jffs2 and f2fs.


@JoepvanSteen AFAIK, USB flash drives use very crude wear leveling where e.g. if you repeatedly overwrite a single logical block this get wear-levelled to overwriting eight different physical blocks in turn. Still, its those eight blocks that will wear out very quickly and determine the physical life of your flash drive.
If, however, you use a log-structured file system then no file system change (be it creation, deletion or modification) will ever write to the same block as writes get distributed approximately evenly across all physical blocks.

@JoepvanSteen indeed, my mistake and I have now fixed that in the response (adding "proper"). This change does not seem to otherwise invalidate my response, though.

I did not make the general statement that you claim I made. On the contrary, there's an explicit "may be" qualifier in that sentence.

This is a software issue more than a hardware issue

involves writing to multiple CSV files multiple times per second

If you are writing multiple CSV files multiple times per second to a flash drive, then it means you are probably not using your RAM properly.  RAM is designed for this kind of read-write load but flash drives are designed for long-term storage; so, instead of saving your CSV data to files multiple times per second, you should just hold that kind of data in memory by assigning your CSV to a variable and letting it live there until such time that you actually need to save it.  While I don't know your exact use case, I imagine that you have just a few CSVs that you are constantly overwriting, but if you store that data in RAM and only commit it to file storage once every few second or minutes or when someone presses the "save" button, then your application will run MUCH faster and put way less undue strain on your flashdrive.
